# Kotlin .run scoped function - method 'void <init>()' not found

Tags: kotlin

I have a problem with the following code snippet:

*(Some functions' bodies are ommited for clear view)*

```
fun collectLinks(page: Page): List<String> {

    return LinksCrawler().run {
        page.accept(this)
        this.links
    }
}

class LinksCrawler {

    private var _links = mutableListOf<String>()
    val links
        get() = _links.toList()


    fun visit(page: Page) { (...) }

    fun visit(container: Container) = { (...) }

    private fun visit(elements: List<HtmlElement>){ (...) }
}
```

When I invoke collectLinks() I get

> Visitor$LinksCrawler: method 'void ()' not found

*(where Visitor is my filename)*

As far as I believe, problem would be caused by scope function .run(), maybe that it has no initialisation code that would do sth with LinksCrawler, but correct me if I am wrong.

I do it in .kts file, if it has any meaning. In overall, it is supposed to be an example for a Visitor design pattern. Full file code below:

```
import Visitor.HtmlElement.Image as Image
import Visitor.HtmlElement.Link as Link
import Visitor.HtmlElement.Table as Table
import Visitor.HtmlElement.Container as Container

main()

// ---------------

fun main() {
    val page = Page(Container(Image(), Link(), Image()),
    Table(),
    Link(),
    Container(Table(), Link()),
    Container(Image(), Container(Image(), Link())))

    println(collectLinks(page))
}

fun collectLinks(page: Page): List<String> {

    return LinksCrawler().run {
        page.accept(this)
        this.links
    }
}

class LinksCrawler {

    private var _links = mutableListOf<String>()
    val links
        get() = _links.toList()


    fun visit(page: Page) {
        visit(page.elements)
    }

    fun visit(container: Container) = visit(container.elements)

    private fun visit(elements: List<HtmlElement>){
        for (e in elements) {
            when (e) {
                is Container -> e.accept(this)
                is Link -> _links.add(e.href)
                is Image -> _links.add(e.src)
                else -> {}
            }
        }
    }
}

fun Container.accept(feature: LinksCrawler) {
    feature.visit(this)
}

fun Page.accept(feature: LinksCrawler) = feature.visit(this)

class Page(val elements: MutableList<HtmlElement> = mutableListOf()) {

    constructor(vararg elements: HtmlElement) : this(mutableListOf()) {
        for (s in elements) {
            this.elements.add(s)
        }
    }
}

sealed class HtmlElement {

    class Container(val elements: MutableList<HtmlElement> = mutableListOf()) : HtmlElement() {

        constructor(vararg units: HtmlElement) : this(mutableListOf()) {

            for (u in units) {
                this.elements.add(u)
            }
        }
    }

    class Image : HtmlElement() {
        val src: String
            get() = "http://image"
    }

    class Link : HtmlElement() {
        val href : String
        get() = "http://link"
    }

    class Table : HtmlElement()
}
```

Comment: i have no experience running kts files. but [this](https://pl.kotl.in/GGwJuz_HN) runs fine for me. i only changed the imports and removed the invocation of main(). don't know if it is of any help for you.

Comment: it has to do with placing it inside/outside class. I managed to run it as you suggested. I don't yet know the explanation behind it, but thank you @IvoBeckers.